# LanmanRedirector randomly accessing dozens of user backup files on the server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am having a problem where we have 50+ single user backup files open on our file server. The users computers are accessing the files via a process called lanmanredirector for no apparent reason, these files are held open and in some cases there are like 4 or 5 copies of each file open. We can stop this by ending the lanmanredirector process on the users local machine.

Anyone run into this issue before or know as to why this would be happening?

Comment: anything in either the workstation or server logs that looks suspicious?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary.
I forgot to mention that we are using a batch script to automate the backup process. This does not happen to every user though, so far it was only on 2 machines.